# Finding indices at multiple locations in a Tensor at runtime and replacing it with 0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I wish to assign 0 to multiple locations in a Tensor of size = `(n,m)` at runtime.

I computed the indices using the where clause in Tensorflow, and called the `scatter_nd_update` function in order to assign a `tf.constant(0)` at the newly found multiple locations.

```
oscvec = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(sgn2 > 0, sgn1 < 0))
updates = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, [None, None])
oscvec_empty = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, [None])
tf.cond(tf.not_equal(tf.size(oscvec), 0), tf.scatter_nd_update(save_parms, oscvec, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float64)),
        tf.scatter_nd_update(save_parms, oscvec_empty, updates))
```

I will expect `tf.where` returns an empty tensor when the condition if not satisfied, and a non-empty tensor of indices for `save_parms` at some point. I decided to create and empty `oscvec_empty` tensor to deal with cases where the result for `tf.where` returns an empty tensor. But this does not seem to work....as seen from the following error which is generated when the Tensorflow if-else condition - `tf.cond` - is used to update `save_parms` parameter tensor via the `tf.scatter_nd_update` function:

```
ValueError: Shape must be at least rank 1 but is rank 0 for 'ScatterNdUpdate' (op: 'ScatterNdUpdate') with input shapes: [55], [?,1], [].
```

Is there a way to replace values at multiple locations in the `save_parms` tensor when oscvec is non-empty and not do so, when oscvec is empty? The `sgn` tensor corresponds to the result of sign function applied on `save_parms` based on a given criterion.

Comment: What's your `sgn2` and `sgn1`? Can you give an example?

Comment: Let `vec1 = tf.constant([[ 0.05734377,  0.80147606, -1.2730557 ],
       [ 0.42826906,  1.1943488 , -0.10129673]]), vec2 = tf.constant([ 1.5461133 , -0.38455755, -0.79792875],
       [ 1.5374309 , -1.5657802 ,  0.05546811]], dtype=float32)
sgn1 = tf.sign(vec1), sgn2=tf.sign(vec2)` So basically, both sign1 and sign contain 1, 0 or -1 depending on whether values of vec1 or vec2 contain 0, positive or negative values.

Comment: Do `sgn1` and `sgn2` have the same shape as `save_parms `?

Comment: Yes, sure they do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `tf.where()` instead of such a complex approach in question.

```
import tensorflow as tf

vec1 = tf.constant([[ 0.05734377, 0.80147606, -1.2730557 ], [ 0.42826906, 1.1943488 , -0.10129673]])
vec2 = tf.constant([[ 1.5461133 , -0.38455755, -0.79792875], [ 1.5374309 , -1.5657802 , 0.05546811]])

sgn1 = tf.sign(vec1)
sgn2 = tf.sign(vec2)
save_parms = tf.random_normal(shape=sgn1.shape)
oscvec = tf.where(tf.math.logical_and(sgn2 > 0, sgn1 < 0),tf.zeros_like(save_parms),save_parms)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    save_parms_val, oscvec_val = sess.run([save_parms, oscvec])
    print(save_parms_val)
    print(oscvec_val)

[[ 0.75645643 -0.646291   -1.2194813 ]
 [ 1.5204562  -1.0625905   2.9939709 ]]
[[ 0.75645643 -0.646291   -1.2194813 ]
 [ 1.5204562  -1.0625905   0.        ]]
```

Comment: I wish to save vec1 and vec2 at run-time in a list, call the list and compute sgn1 and sgn2 from the saved tensors in the list. Then discard the list contents after 3 counts. I hope this is optimal- and save_parms will be the last element of the list.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Does tf.zeros_like automatically substitue zero values in save_parms where the index positions are provided by tf.where when the condition is satisfied? I do not know where to mark this an accepted answer.

Comment: @QNNet I don't understand your first comment. `tf.zeros_like` will create a tensor with all elements set to `0` and the same shape as `save_parms `. `tf.where` will replace the value of `save_parms `  where the index positions are provided by `tf.where` when the condition is satisfied. You can also find it by example in answer. In addition, you only need to click check under the voting to accept the answer.

Comment: The example you provided is correct and clear. I mean that, in order to use this, I will have to generate  both `vec1` and `vec2` by running a program. I wonder whether storing both `vec1` at run time in a list which will be accessed later in the program in order to compute `sgn1` and `sgn2` is optimal? Or if there is a way to store tensors in a matrix as in `numpy` and use them when necessary is possible in 'Tensorflow? At the moment, I am using a list.

Comment: @QNNet You don't have to create a new list to save them. You can calculate them whenever you need them since tensorflow is static graph.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. I meant that using a control flow, I can store `vec1` and `vec2` before performing the above action. U mean I can possibly retrieve these tensors say, at `k-th` and `(k-1) - th` position using tensorflow static graph property? For example, `matpvals = []; for k in range(someEpoch):  vec1 = .. ; vec2 = ...; matpvals.append(vec1) ; matpvals.append(vec2); if len(matpvals) == 2: calltfwherefunction(matpvals). ` The call to `tfwherefunction` is performed when the len of the list is 2.

Comment: How do I find out when the graph contains 3 Tensors? Because I will want a list to be discarded after using contents of the list/graph containing 3 tensors.

Comment: @QNNet Maybe your need [`tf.Graph.control_dependencies`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph#control_dependenciess) to support static graph operation like `with g.control_dependencies([vec1, vec2]):
 calltfwherefunction(matpvals)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will take a look at it. But this module does not represent control low? I havve to pass both tensors before performing the required action on them?